# On the weak closure of a sequence of projections

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with $\text{dim}=\infty$ , and $\{e_n\}$ be an orthogonal sequence of projections in $B(H)$. Show that $\{\sqrt{n}e_n ; n\geq 1\}$ does not admit a subsequence converging to zero weakly.

Suppose $\{\sqrt{n_k}e_{n_k}\}$ be a weakly convergent subsequence to zero , so 
$$\sqrt{n_{k}}e_{n_k}\to 0 (\text{wot}) \Longrightarrow \sqrt{n_k} \langle e_{n_k}\xi,\eta\rangle \to 0~~~(\xi,\eta\in H)$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\Longrightarrow \{\sqrt{n_k}\langle e_{n_k} \xi , \eta\rangle\} \text{is norm bounded}$$
Now I need to show the above subsequence is not bounded for a contradiction.

While I'm sure  that the subsequence is not bounded, but I can not show it. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You probably mean nonzero projections $e_n.$

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk : Yes, exactly

Comment: Are $\{e_n\}$ generic orthogonal projections? The writing suggests they are the projections on the $n_{th}$ direction...

Comment: @Saphrosit: They are orthogonal projections.

Comment: Are they mutually orthogonal projections, i.e., $e_k e_k' = 0$ for $k\ne k'$?

Comment: @T.A.E. : Yes. They are mutually orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{\sqrt{n_k}e_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be an arbitrary subsequence of $\{\sqrt{n}e_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. It is clear that $k\leq n_k$. For each positive integer $k$, there exists
$\xi_k\in H$ such that $\| \xi_k\|=1$ and $e_{n_k}\xi_k=\xi_k$. Define the sequence of numbers $\{ \alpha_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ as follows: $\alpha_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n_k}}$ if $k$ is a power of $2$, i.e., if $k=2^m$ for some positive integer $m$; for $k\ne 2^m$, let $\alpha_k=0$. It follows that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_k|^2=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_{2^m}|^2\leq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2^m}}<\infty. \tag1 $$
Thus $\xi=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\alpha_k\xi_k$ is well defined vector in $H$. It follows from
$$ \langle \sqrt{n_k}e_{n_k}\xi,\xi\rangle=\sqrt{n_k}\alpha_{k}^{2}=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 1; & k=2^m\\ 0; & k\ne 2^m\end{array} \right. $$
that the sequence $\{ \langle \sqrt{n_k}e_{n_k}\xi,\xi\rangle\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge to $0$ and therefore $\{ \sqrt{n_k}e_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge  to $0$ in the weak operator topology.

Comment: Why do you suppose $k\leq n_k$?

Comment: You do not show the subsequence is not norm bounded. Would you show it too?

Comment: @niki I think that I proved that $\{ \sqrt{n}e_n\}$ does not have a subsequence which converges weakly to $0$. I don't believe that your claim about unboundedness is correct. The obvious inequality $k\leq n_k$ I used in for the estimate in (1).

Comment: But I have given a hint (any subsequence of $\{n^{1/2}e_n\}$ is unbounded; hence the uniform boundedness theorem applies.)

Comment: I think we should show there is not any subsequence converging to zero weakly, not just for a certain subsequence. Is not it?

Comment: @niki Yes, maybe it is possible to solve the exercise also in your way: if $\{ \langle\sqrt{n_k}e_{n_k}\xi,\eta\rangle\} $ converges to $0$ for any $\xi, \eta$, then it is bounded and now UBP gives boundedness of $\{ \sqrt{n_k}e_{n_k}\}$ which is impossible.

Comment: @niki I think we have now two solutions. In my solution I constructed some vectors explicitly to show that the sequence of the related scalars does not converge to $0$.

Comment: @niki But it is proved for any subsequence. The inequality $k\leq n_k$ is not an assumption, it is a fact which always holds.

Comment: But if I choose the subsequence in such way that $k>n_k$ then I can not show  desired result.

Comment: @niki I am sure that you cannot do it: $k$ are integers $1,2,3,...$ but $n_1$ is some positive integer, so $1\leq n_1$. Then $n_2$ must be larger than $n_1$, so $2\leq n_2$, etc. This means how is made the subsequence.

Comment: It seems ok. Thanks for your attention.